# Unsure of how to use the Authorize tag for jwt cookie authentication, please advice

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using asp.net core and to authenticate users I'm using jwt token authentication, and the token I generate (if the users login details are valid) are stored in a cookie. However, I've seen people using the [Authenticate] tag to authorize users, instead of calling an authentication method when a user attempts to access a controller
(code for reference) :

```
public Response ValidateToken(HttpContext context, string jwtToken)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
            var secretKey = GetTokenSecret();
            var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey)),
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidAudience = _config["Jwt:Audience"],
                ValidIssuer = _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                ValidateSignatureLast = true,
            };
            const string alg = "HS256";
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            JwtSecurityToken validJwt = new JwtSecurityToken();
            try
            {
                var principal = handler.ValidateToken(jwtToken, validationParameters, out var validToken);
                validJwt = validToken as JwtSecurityToken;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { 
                if(ex.Message.Contains("Signature validation failed. Token does not have a kid") || ex.Message.Contains("Unable to decode the") || ex.Message.Contains("null"))
                {
                    return new Response { status = false, message = "Login token cannot be validated. Please relogin to validate\"" };
                }
                else
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
            if (validJwt == null)
            {
                return new Response { status = true, message = null };
            }
            if (!validJwt.Header.Alg.Equals(alg, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                return new Response { status = false, message = "Login token cannot be validated. Please relogin to validate\"" };
            }
            return new Response { status = true, message = null };
        }
```

Here's my Startup.cs code for reference too :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using JokesApp.Business;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using System.Configuration;

namespace JokesApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        CommonFunctions commonFunctions;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public Startup(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
            commonFunctions = new CommonFunctions(config);            
        }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = configuration.GetValue<string>("Jwt:Issuer"),
                    ValidAudience = configuration.GetValue<string>("Jwt:Audience"),
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration.GetValue<string>("Jwt:Key")))
                };
            });
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if(env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make the authentication tag work, but I'm still unsure of how it really works. applying it to, for example, my home controller, keeps redirecting me to a default login page. I'm unsure of how to deal with this, or how to make this properly work, so it would be helpful if someone gave me some insight into how the `[Authorize]` tag works, and how I can create a function to authenticate appropriate to jwt

Answer (score 0):

For how to use `[Authorize]` attribute, you can add it on top of a controller or  just a method inside a controller.
You can also reference Microsoft document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-7.0

If you are confused about cookie and jwt authentication procedure.
For cookie authentication like

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("auth1").AddCookie("auth1");
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
```

It will verify if the request have a header `"Cookies"` with value `".AspNetCore.auth1=xxxxxxxx"`
Then every method with `[Authorize]` will need this validate.

An explaination about "auth1":
I have a authentication controller which people can post with userName and password ,then it will return the browser a cookie.

```
public class AuthenticateController : Controller
    {
        [Route("/authenticate")]     
        public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate([FromQuery]string usr, [FromQuery]string pwd)
        {
            if (usr == "admin" && pwd == "123")
            {
                var userClaims = new List<Claim>()            //if api request user name and password is right,create user claim
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, usr),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "admin@eshop.com"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.HomePhone, "12345678")
                };

                var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(userClaims,"auth1");     //create identity scheme with the claim and name it "auth1"
                var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync("auth1", userPrincipal);    //return the browser a cookie named ".AspNetCore.auth1=xxxxxxxx"
                return Redirect("/userpage");
            }            

            return Redirect("/");
        }

        [Route("/logout")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();

            return Redirect("/welcome");
        }
    }
```

The "auth1" is a identity scheme which can be used at program.cs like

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("auth1").AddCookie("auth1");
```

For jwt authentication like

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                     .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
                    {
                        options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";

                        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            ValidateAudience = false
                        };
                    });
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
```

It will verify if the request have a header `"Authorization"` with value `"bearer {tokenValue}"` 
Then every method with `[Authorize]` will need this validate.

Not like cookie is automatically added when using broswer. You need add a "Authorization" header manualy.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you re-explain how this code works and what does it do?
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("auth1").AddCookie("auth1");

Comment: @YanSoo I have added some explaination to this answer you can have check. I also recommad this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sogS0DtejVA